# Image Map links not working in IE or Firefox

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, imagemap

I can get the image map on this page: http://dlibrary.libguides.com/content.php?pid=611371&sid=5051634 to open links in Chrome, but not in IE and Firefox. Originally my image map names didn't have the #, so I added it, but that still didn't fix the problem. I created the image map with: http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap
Here's the code:

```
    <p><img    src="http://lgimages.s3.amazonaws.com/data/imagemanager/77096/fall_instruction_menu2014.jpg" alt="menu page 1" height="1650" width="1275" usemap="#imgmap201472214596" />
<map id="#imgmap201472214596" name="#imgmap201472214596">
<area shape="rect" alt="Intro to College Research Presentation" title="Intro to College Research Presentation" coords="69,240,511,287" href="http://lgdata.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/docs/2717/1161608/Research_for_College.pdf" target="_blank" />
<area shape="rect" alt="Scholarly vs Popular Resources Presentation" title="Scholarly vs Popular Resources Presentation" coords="73,875,605,920" href="http://lgdata.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/docs/2717/1161609/Scholarly_vs_Popular.pdf" target="_blank" />
<area shape="rect" alt="Writing Research Questions Presentation" title="Writing Research Questions Presentation" coords="75,1000,541,1062" href="http://lgdata.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/docs/2717/1161610/Research_Questions.pdf" target="_blank" />
<area shape="rect" alt="Developing Search Terms Presentation" title="Developing Search Terms Presentation" coords="76,1147,504,1197" href="http://lgdata.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/docs/2717/1161611/Developing_Search_Terms.pdf" target="_blank" />
<area shape="rect" alt="Database Search Strategies Presentation" title="Database Search Strategies Presentation" coords="73,1325,535,1373" href="http://lgdata.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/docs/2717/1161612/Search_Strategies_for_Databases.pdf" target="_blank" /><!-- Created by Online Image Map Editor (http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/index) --></map></p><p>
    <img src="http://lgimages.s3.amazonaws.com/data/imagemanager/77096/fall_instruction_menu20142.jpg" alt="menu page 2" height="1650" width="1275" usemap="#imgmap2014722155240"/>
<map id="#imgmap2014722155240" name="#imgmap2014722155240">
<area shape="rect" alt="Ultimate Research Combo Presentation" title="Ultimate Research Combo Presentation" coords="72,725,854,812" href="http://lgdata.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/docs/2717/1161613/Ultimate_Research_Combo.pdf" target="_blank" /><!-- Created by Online Image Map Editor (http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/index) --></map></p>
```

What could be preventing the links from opening in IE and Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `<image />` tag, this is correct: `usemap="#imgmap201472214596"`

The `usemap` is a reference to a `name` of a `<map />` without the hashtag:

```
<map id="imgmap201472214596" name="imgmap201472214596">
                                   ^----------
```

I am pretty sure when you remove tha `#` and make sure all tags are properly written and all quotation marks are intact, it is going to work.

Comment: Yes! That was it! Thank you so much. I knew it was something silly that I wasn't noticing. I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem :-) I admit, it may be confusing, why they want the `#` in `usemap` ?